# How to execute batch file as Tortoise SVN hook

Tags: windows, batch-file, tortoisesvn

I wish to run a batch file either in START commit or PRE commit via TortoiseSVN hook scripts. No tests I have done has worked.

I have created a batch file (svnadd.bat) that just writes a message to a text file for now, so I know it fired. However, the batch file does not appear to run as the message does not get written.

```
echo YES>C:\Temp\commit.txt
```

Here is my hook setup.
[image]

My process. Right click on a folder which is under svn version control and select SVN Commit. The commit dialog shows, however, the batch file does not execute.

All svn software, repositories and folder/file structure under svn control reside on the same computer/drive.

As per the screen shot, I also tried adding cmd.exe to the front of the command line as

```
C:\windows\system32\cmd.exe /c C:\Tools\SVN\svnadd.bat
```

Comment: Do you have WC on path c:\Tools/SVN/ ?

Comment: sorry, what do you mean by 'WC'?

Comment: **W**orking **C**opy of any repository, obviously

Comment: Repository checked out as C:\Projects\Client\ClientName. C:\Tools is not under source control.

Comment: `C:\Projects\Client\ClientName` **must be** in Path-field, because this is single link between *one of hooks* and *one of WCs* on your workplace (see at window with open eyes). I had some strange problems with start-commit hook in my test, but others (really usable) works without any problem

Comment: Thank you! that was it. I just made it C:\ and it worked. Seems a strange required field in that I could checkout projects to different drives. thankfully I don't and C:\ `path` is enough. If you feel you have the time, please add it as a quick answer and I will edit it properly if needed and accept it. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@lazybadger's comment provides the answer in that the "path" needs to be at the highest working copy path. For me, this is `C:\Projects`.

Once I set `C:\Projects` as the path, the script hook ran.

Answer (score 1):

I config it like this. It is successful.

post_commit_hook.bat:

```
echo Hello World >file.txt
```

After commit, file.txt will be save to

```
E:\SVN\XXX\branches\autoCommit
```

[image: config]

Answer (score -4):

You can try and use team city, if you want certain scripts to be executed on SVN events (like SVN Commit). Though TeamCity is mainly used as a build server, I think it can do what you desire.